# Add an oversized logo image to a fixed bottom navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a logo as the brand on a fixed-bottom navbar.
The logo is larger than the navbar itself.  I want it to overlap the body, but instead it hangs below the top of the links.

I don't know what element to style in to change.

```
.navbar {
height:72px;
background: transparent;
background-image: url("../images/nav-bkgd.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border: 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: "Bangers","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
letter-spacing: 2px;
padding-left: 35px;
padding-right: 35px;
}


.navbar-fixed-bottom {
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1030;
 }

.navbar-fixed-bottom  {
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}

<body>
```

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src='assets/images/logo.png'</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#">TROPOSHPERE</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#">STRATOSPHERE</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#">MESOSPHERE</a>
                </li>
               <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#">THERMOSPHERE</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#">EXOSPHERE</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
.navbar-brand img {
    margin-top: -16px;
}
```

I just put -16px as a random measurement but tweak it to match what you want of course.

Also the img tag within the link isn't closed (missing **/>**)